# Product of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u,v\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $p > n$. Show that $uv \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and moreover that $uv$ satisfies the inequality:
$$
\|uv\|_{W^{1,p}} \leq C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}\|v\|_{W^{1,p}}
$$

The idea here seems to be to use the Sobolev inequality (Gagliardo Nirenberg) to get some sort of quantitative estimate on $\|uv\|$, however I am even having issues showing the product is in $L^p$. A small hint or idea would be appreciated. I also think we may want to approximate $u,v$ with test functions, as we have the full space $\mathbb{R}^n$ to our disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the terms you have to bound look like $L^p$ norms of $uv$, $v\partial_i u$ or $u\partial_i v$ for some $i=1,\ldots,n$. To do this just recall that for $p>n$ and $w\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ we have $w\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ and 
$$
\| w\|_{L^\infty}\lesssim \| w\|_{W^{1,p}}.
$$

Comment: This makes sense thank you. When bounding the derivative, it seems to be I need to use the product rule for weak derivatives. How would I show that it holds? Just using test functions and then passing to the limit?

Comment: @rubikscube09: yeah, that's pretty much how you do it.